# I'm having an error with the pdo in php mysql "Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpunit

Hello, I'm having an error with PDO in PHP MySQL and I don't know what to do. Is it any configuration? Use the easyphp grateful

file of conections .php

```
<?php
abstract class Conexao
{
    const USER = "root";
    const PASS = "";
    const DB   = "pare_aqui_db";
    const HOST = "localhost";
    private static $instancia = null;

    private static function conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            if(self::$instancia == null):
                $sqlPDO = "mysql:host=".self::HOST.";dbname=".self::DB;
                self::$instancia == new PDO( $sqlPDO , self::USER , self::PASS );
                self::$instancia->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instancia->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            endif;
        }
        catch(PDOException $erro_conecta){echo "erro".$erro_conecta->getMessage();}
        return self::$instancia;
    }

    protected static function getDB()
    {
        return self::conectar();        
    }
}
 ?>
```

error when testing the page in chrome
Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\pare_aqui_web_service\Dconecta.class.php on line 17

the prepare () also does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self::$instancia == new
```

is not setting the variable. Therefore `self::$instancia->setAttribute` is triggering the error because you are executing `(NULL)->setAttribute` on a non object.

That was obviously a typo but just in case: `==` is the comparator operator; what you are really looking for is `=` which is the *assignment* operator; therefore the correct code is:

```
self::$instancia = new PDO( $sqlPDO , self::USER , self::PASS );
```

Comment: You might want to suggest what the op _should_ do to make this work, as well?

Comment: @ColinMorelli, *gimme time*